Tag tooltips in the staging ground get clipped
Steps to Reproduce:

Open the Staging Ground
Hover over any of the first tags or scroll such that only the top / bottom of the table that lists posts is visible and then hover on a tag.

Expected Result: Tooltip is fully visible.
Actual: Tooltip gets clipped.


For any staff happening on this, this was already reported in the beta phase. Just posting this here so that it can be tracked on Meta instead.

bug Similarly, if you hover a tag at the bottom of the listing, the hover will appear within the element listing the items, overflowing, and causing a vertical scrollbar to appear, which you need to scroll down to see the tag tooltip. I'd expect the tooltip to either be smart and show up above if there's no space below or something.

Oh, yep indeed, took me a while to understand what you meant (a Screenshot could be useful maybe..., I had not discovered "this one", ah-ah...!). It actually happens for the last 3 rows/items in the 'SG' main View, and for all Tags, not only the first one on the left, they all get truncated horizontally at the bottom, and the vertical scrollbar appears, ... but that scrollbar is un-scrollable as it disappears as soon as the mouse moves out of the Tag or the Tag-Popup... ('Arrow-Down' / 'Space' / 'PageDown' / 'Ctrl^PageDown' / 'Ctrl^End' all do nothing...)

Oh yep, middle-mouse scrolling is the only thing that works indeed... // Forgot to mention, @starball, but you have a typo in "veritcal"...

This is a valid bug report and a legitimate concern, but we're marking it as status-declined. We spent some time on it this sprint but weren't able to come up with a good working solution. There's a tradeoff between making this page work on mobile browsers and making the tag hover work - and we'd prefer to have the mobile view work.

Have you considered just using a media query for desktop views and a higher z-index level? Poorly z-ordered elements should not be a particularly difficult design obstacle to overcome in 2024.

There's a wealth of information on how to deal with this particular problem right here on Stack Overflow

Also, what are the stats on people accessing the Staging Ground as reviewers from mobile vs desktop? Surely it's overwhelmingly favoring the desktop view? This is a rather odd preference to make.

It only happens on the main 'SG' View Page but works very correctly on any 'Search' Page, or any 'Recent Qt's for Tag X' Page, can't you adopt the same Design...?

Finally, shouldn't this be 'status-deferred', instead? Or are you promising you truly never plan to revisit or attempt to fix this bug?

I don't know what mobile functionality you're even talking about... on mobile that popup doesn't even appear unless you tap the tag, then click the back button because it navigated to a tag page... then you can't make the popup go away... where's my close button... is this why the stats on the ignore button being pressed was so whack? On mobile the tooltip flows over the review controls rather than under them, like the content it's for does.

Appreciate the feedback here. The problem isn't a Z-index problem, it's an overflow problem. It's caused by the .s-table-container on the parent, which allows this table to scroll horizontally on smaller viewports with overflow-x: auto. We're not using this table in the other places that were called out. When I say that we prefer the mobile functionality, I'm meaning that we want this table to scroll on smaller viewports.

"There's a tradeoff between making this page work on mobile browsers and making the tag hover work - and we'd prefer to have the mobile view work." - Stack Overflow exists specifically to fill the needs of people who will use it to do work on desktop. Have you ever had a terminal app running on your phone and used an on-screen keyboard to run a build command or test a CLI program? If that's the experience that the company intends to privilege, all is lost.

Depending how you want to look at the problem @KylePollard if .s-post-summary didn't have position: relative then the overflow on .s-table-container wouldn't be an issue. Of course, this would also require changing the position calculation in showingPopup, but just a different solution that would give similar results if it were easier to unset that property than it is to modify the global table container behaviour.
